# Abnormally high battery drain

Tags: battery, nexus-5

My battery drains extremely quickly, it can deplete completely in just over 1 hour.  It can even drain faster than the charger can supply.

Here is the battery graph after less than 60 minutes of load (this was playing candy crush saga).

Is this normal behaviour or is there something wrong with my phone?

The numbers in the usage stats don't add up to 100% either, it just says Screen 13%, facebook 8%, candy crush 4%, android system 2%, and a few other little 1% apps.

1 year old Nexus 5 with android version 5.0, kernel 3.4.0-g88fbc66

[image]

Comment: Is your device rooted? If yes, have you installed any custom ROM? If yes, then ROM could be a possible reason. Try another ROM/flash stock ROM back in your device. If this does not help/phone is not rooted, then it could be a hardware issue. (I faced the same issue with my SGS2, and buying a new battery solved it.)

Comment: Hi!  The device is rooted, but I don't have any custom ROM installed

Comment: My guess is a malware app. A little torrent server?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not normal. It could be that you need to re calibrate/replace your battery. This is the ultimate solution if nothing else you try works. Otherwise I would suggest either trying different versions of Android, or switching over to a custom ROM and see if that helps.